# Use angular material in wordpress as a plugin

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, angular-material

I am creating a plugin for wordpress which uses angular material as part of it. I want to use a datepicker in the front page for some pages, and when I add everything, the date picker table does not have the good styling.

I think this happens due to style overrides that wordpress theme has. Does anyone know how to integrate angular material with wordpress? I am using "wp_enqueue_script" and "wp_enqueue_style" to load javascript and stylesheet files.

Is it possible to use angular material datepicker in wordpress and somehow make it keep its styling?

Comment: Issue has nothing to do with angular-material specifically. Whenever you combine css frameworks you are bound to have collisions that require additional more specific over rides to achieve style you want

Comment: You are right. I am trying to figure out how one can achieve this.

Comment: You need to inspect live html and see what rules are impacting the elements that aren't what you want them to be and over ride those rules